# Cannot git clone Apparmor kernel patches

Tags: kernel, application-development, git, apparmor, porting-ubuntu-touch

Whenever I enter (git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/jj/ubuntu-utopic.git) into the terminal, I get this output:

Cloning into 'ubuntu-utopic'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

How do I fix this and what may be the problem so I can fix it if it happens again.

Comment: They've disabled it. Probably accidentally.  The fastest way to fix that is to find some developer in the Ubuntu IRC chat and ask to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the issue here. It looks like the Git repository doesn't exist or is inaccessible.

You can't do anything about it but contact the maintainer(s) or find another clone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic) has become unsupported, that repository is probably not maintained anymore. I recommend cloning current branch, either 15.04 (Vivid)<sup>[1]</sup> (actually unsupported now, but still maintained because it's the base for current phone image) or 16.04 (Xenial)<sup>[2]</sup> repo.

To port AppArmor for your kernel tree, look for the branches for phone image, preferably for similar Linux version or phone chipset/model, and then cherry-pick the commit saying "Sync to apparmor 3 - RC1 snapshot".

You'll also have to cherry-pick the commit that says "binder: search for receiving context pid in global namespace", as it's required for trust-store system.

Note that if your phone's kernel is v3.4 or lower (maybe also some higher version, but I'm not so sure), you'll have to backport Bluetooth stack from newer kernel too. See commit about that in those branches for information.

[1] http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-vivid.git/
[2] http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/